# Android emojicon

Tags: android, emoji

I'm trying to use the library in this [link](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon), I've done the import with no issues, once I add the library in using right click on the project -> properties -> Android -> then add the Emojicon, Eclipse complains about the library android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

The code I'm using is this, which is copied from the example provided by the author of the library.

The Libraries added to my project are 
appcompat_v7
Emojicon 
And also tried adding the example as a library and that didn't help. Anyone had this issue?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;//
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconGridFragment;
import com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconsFragment;
import com.rockerhieu.emojicon.emoji.Emojicon;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements EmojiconGridFragment.OnEmojiconClickedListener, EmojiconsFragment.OnEmojiconBackspaceClickedListener {
    EditText mEditEmojicon;
    TextView mTxtEmojicon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mEditEmojicon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmojicon);
        mTxtEmojicon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmojicon);
        mEditEmojicon.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                mTxtEmojicon.setText(s);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmojiconClicked(Emojicon emojicon) {
        EmojiconsFragment.input(mEditEmojicon, emojicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEmojiconBackspaceClicked(View v) {
        EmojiconsFragment.backspace(mEditEmojicon);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does mean "Eclipse complains about the library android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" ?

Comment: what exact errors are you getting?

Comment: paste the exact errors

Comment: Did you add the android.support.v4 library to your build path?

Comment: I'm also assuming that you followed the directions in [here](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon/wiki/Building-in-Eclipse)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I lost internet in my house, the android.support.v4 library is already there as you can see in the attached picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is occur by below reason:

1. May be your android support v4 library is not same for all.
2. May be you are not using updated android support v4 library.
3. May be your project is getting same jar file more then one.

so fixed this problem please clean your project and use updated android support v4 library and use only one jar file which is placed lib folder of library project.

Comment: The error I'm getting is this "The import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity cannot be resolved", and the support library is already there, will check for duplicates though.